# SQL combine SELECT statements AND display them both

Tags: sql, select

The first SELECT statement display the recent changes based on timestamp.

```
SELECT Item, Bin, Counted, Updates FROM TB_BinLoc x WHERE x.Updates > {ts '2020-12-16 14:00:00'}
```

Next I also want to select same items from the generated list where Bin='MASTER' and change Counted = 0

```
UNION
SELECT Item, Bin, Counted, Updates FROM TB_BinLoc y WHERE x.Item = y.Item AND y.Bin = 'MASTER'
```

Essentially, What I want here is to display the first list based on timestamp, The first list do not have any bin=MASTER. Next, I want to select items from the first list where bin=MASTER and change the Counted quantity to 0, then display the result.

Thank You

Comment: you want to change the Counted quantity to 0 in select or in the table?

Comment: After the list generated from timestamp, display it, then use the list to select items where bin=MASTER and set Counted to 0 and display them also.  so if the first list is 10 changes, then next display is 10 for a total of 20 row display

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I ended up with:

```
SELECT cItemno, cWarehouse, cBin, nCounted, Updates FROM TB_BinLoc WHERE Updates > {ts '2020-12-17 05:00:00'}
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT y.cItemno, y.cWarehouse, y.cBin, y.nCounted, y.Updates
FROM TB_BinLoc y
JOIN TB_BinLoc x on y.cItemno = x.cItemno
Where y.cBin = 'MASTER' AND y.cWarehouse = 'MAIN'
AND x.Updates > {ts '2020-12-17 05:00:00'}
 ORDER BY cBin ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

You could combine both conditions with the logical `or` operator:

```sql
SELECT Item, Bin, Counted, Updates
FROM   TB_BinLoc
WHERE  Updates > {ts '2020-12-16 14:00:00'} OR Bin = 'MASTER'
```

Comment: I don't know who voted  you up, but your response is quite OFF!

Answer (score 1):

You should use `union` operator

```
SELECT Item, Bin, Counted, Updates
FROM   TB_BinLoc
WHERE  Updates > {ts '2020-12-16 14:00:00'}
UNION 
SELECT Item, Bin, 0 Counted, Updates
FROM   TB_BinLoc
WHERE  Updates > {ts '2020-12-16 14:00:00'} and Bin = 'MASTER'
```

Comment: about ' after MASTER you are write, but in correct syntax near ',' and from?
Are you using MS SQL?

Comment: yes, I am using MS SQL. the comma after the CASE.  and the first FROM

Comment: sorry case left,please try

Comment: it only display the first list.  work half way

Comment: for second list this query wrong
`SELECT Item, Bin, 0 Counted, Updates
FROM   TB_BinLoc
WHERE  Updates > {ts '2020-12-16 14:00:00'} and Bin = 'MASTER'`

Answer (score 1):

If you want bin and counted to meet the condition together, you should use 'and', if either of them satisfies you should use 'or'

```
    SELECT Item, Bin, Counted, Updates
    FROM   TB_BinLoc
    WHERE  Updates > {ts '2020-12-16 14:00:00'} 
    AND Bin = 'MASTER'
    AND Counted=0
```